# Firebase user in multiple activities

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have three activities:

- MainActivity
- phone_verification
- HomeActivity

In the `MainActivity` i use google signIn authentication provided by Firebase and in Phone_verification Activity i use phone verification system provided by Firebase. In HomeActivity i will be printing all the details of the current user by creating the object of `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` method , but every time only Phone number will be printed on HomeActivity without any other details such as email, displayName, and other details. What i think is the FirebaseAuth object that i use in both the activities `MainActivity` and `Phone_verifivation` is two different objects.

How can i use the same `FirebaseAuth` object that i used in `MainActivity` in `Phone_verification` ?

Comment: So you say that you get the information from the FirebaseUser object in an activity, in not on the other?

Comment: in MainActivity.java new FirebaseAuth object is created and is authenticated with google accounts . But in the Phone_verification.java inside the method `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential` the FirebaseAuth object gets modified (or would have created new object) and all the information authenticated in the previous activity is lost and it presently stores only phone number only.

Comment: and is there any way to **update** the present user phone number using Firebase

Comment: My `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential` is as follows

Comment: `private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());`

Comment: `if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(phone_verification.this,"invalid OTP try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
`

Comment: `TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                            textView.setText("done"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()+"done");
                            updateUI(user);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }`

Comment: I think problem is in the  `mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential) ` method in the `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential` method which is creating new FirebaseAuth object and replacing the previously created FirebaseAuth object in MainActivity.java

Comment: So is there any way of dealing with the same FirebaseAuth object?